# Is the ToArray method of a Stack<T> guaranteed to return in this order?

Tags: c#, stack

I have a [`Stack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1), which I am using to stack int-tuples. Right now, I am using the following code to return a copy of the stack, sorted from oldest to newest:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> GetAllTuples()
{
    return this.ToArray<Tuple<int,int>>().Reverse<Tuple<int,int>>();
}
```

This works, but I am worried that the ordering returned by `ToArray()` may not be guaranteed in all cases. The documentation of `ToArray()` states the following:

> The elements are copied onto the array in last-in-first-out (LIFO) order, similar to the order of the elements returned by a succession of calls to Pop.

Is it safe to assume that in the future, calls to `ToArray()` (and thus by extension, `.Reverse()`) will return the same order? I'm a bit thrown off by "similar to". If not, how can I ensure that the tuples will be returned from oldest to newest?

---

To illustrate my point further, here is an example:

```
Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
stack.Push(1);
stack.Push(2);
stack.Push(3);
stack.Push(4);
stack.Push(5);

int[] toArr = stack.ToArray<int>(); // Yields [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
int[] toArrReverse = toArr.Reverse<int>(); // Yields [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], which is what I want.
```

Comment: The behavior is documented. It's not going to change. You have my word :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I'll hold you accountable when my code breaks ;)

Comment: It's probably more efficient to use `Array.Reverse` because it uses the same array. Perhaps you should be using a `Queue` which uses FIFO instead of `Stack`, obviating the need for `Reverse`

Comment: @Charlieface While editing, semantically it behaves like a stack. However, when "finalizing", steps are traced from oldest to newest. Besides, it'll only ever include a handful of elements (think less than 10), so sorting will still be relatively quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/stack.cs,257d8a090a3bf13a) piece from Microsoft documentation saying that ToArray

> Copies the Stack to an array, in the same order Pop would return the
> items.

confirms the behavior you are observing.

```
    // Copies the Stack to an array, in the same order Pop would return the items.
    public virtual Object[] ToArray()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Object[]>() != null);

        Object[] objArray = new Object[_size];
        int i = 0;
        while(i < _size) {
            objArray[i] = _array[_size-i-1];
            i++;
        }
        return objArray;
    }
```

**Edit**: When you think about it, it make sense - by definition the only way to get the items out of a stack is to Pop them (last in first out). The same should be true when all of items are being taken out (or just being copied like with ToArray). This will only happen one item at a time. If it behaves otherwise, IMHO, it will clearly violate the core idea of Stack.

Comment: Even with source code attached, what a luxury. Thank you very much for the quick response.

Comment: Just be mindful that the source code is for non-generic Stack type. However I do not have a reason to doubt that generic Stack could implement the same method differently.

Comment: "The same should be true when all of items are being taken out (or just being copied like with ToArray). This will only happen one item at a time." - I'm not sure what you are trying to say here. No, it will *not* happen "one item at a time", because the entire array will be returned as a whole. "If it behaves otherwise, IMHO, it will clearly violate the core idea of Stack." - one *could* argue that retrieving all the items from the stack without removing them already does violate that core idea. On the other hand, if *peeking* is ok, then the order of peeking should be irrelevant.

Comment: "The entire array will be returned as a whole" agree. But that array will be populated one item at a time from the stack, in an iteration. And the core idea is that this one item that's being read from stack, should be the last item on it. Hope it clarifies my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, the elements are copied onto the array in last-in-first-out (LIFO) order, similar to the order of the elements returned by a succession of calls to `Pop`.

So, this looks as a strict contract which fully defines the order. There is no remarks that this is implementation specific and is a subject to change in future.

So, I believe that we can rely on the current behaviour for now and in the future.